# Continuous iff Oscillation is zero

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For  a bounded function $f:D\subset \Bbb R^n \rightarrow  \Bbb R$, $b$ in $\Bbb R^n$,   and a real number $\delta>0$. Define the following:

$M(f,b,\delta)$=sup{f(x)$: x$ in $D$ and $||x-b||<\delta$}

$m(f,b,\delta)$=inf{f(x)$: x$ in $D$ and $||x-b||<\delta$}

Define the oscillation of $f$ in $b$ as:

$o(f,b)= \lim\limits_{\delta \to 0} \ (M(f,b,\delta)-m(f,b,\delta))$

Prove that $f$ is continuous in $b$ if and only if $o(f,b)=0$

The first direction would be easier if we had a closed interval. As this one is closed, I haven't figured out how to prove the first implication. Also, what would you suggest for the second one?

For the converse, it it enough to say that if  $||x-b||< \hat{\delta}$ then $||f(x)-f(b)||\leq|| M(f,b,\hat{\delta})-m(f,b,\hat{\delta})||\leq \epsilon$ ?

Comment: There should be no $\delta$ among the arguments of $o$, and in the definitions of $M$ and $m$, you wrote $y$ in place of $b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous at $b$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\hat{\delta}> 0 $, which may depend upon $b$, such that if $||x-b|| < \hat{\delta}$, then $||f(x) - f(b)|| < \epsilon/2$.

Suppose $x,y \in D \cap B(b;\hat{\delta}).$  Then

$$f(x) < f(b) + \epsilon/2 \\ \sup \{f(x):x \in D , ||x-b||< \hat{\delta}\} \leq f(b) + \epsilon/2$$

and

$$f(y) > f(b) - \epsilon/2 \\ \inf \{f(x):x \in D , ||x-b||< \hat{\delta}\} \geq f(b) - \epsilon/2.$$

Whence,

$$\sup \{f(x):x \in D , ||x-b||< \hat{\delta}\}-\inf \{f(x):x \in D , ||x-b||< \hat{\delta}\}  \\= M(f,b,\hat{\delta})-m(f,b,\hat{\delta})\leq \epsilon.$$

Furthermore, if $\delta \leq \hat{\delta},$ then

$$M(f,b,\delta)-m(f,b,\delta)\leq M(f,b,\hat{\delta})-m(f,b,\hat{\delta})\leq \epsilon,$$

and

$$o(f,b)=\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0}[M(f,b,\delta)-m(f,b,\delta)]=0.$$

Try to use a similar argument to prove the converse.

Comment: Yes -- your inequality for $M$ is correct, but incorrect for $m$.  If $A$ is a subset of $B$, then $inf_{A} f(x) \geq inf_{B} f(x)$.  On the larger set, the minimum of the function could be smaller but never larger than the minimum of the function on the subset.  Also $M-m = sup|f(x)-f(y)|$ and you can see that this non-decreasing as $\delta$ increases.

Comment: You`re right! Thanks!

Comment: For the converse, it it enough to say that if  $||x-b||< \hat{\delta}$ then $||f(x)-f(b)||\leq|| M(f,b,\hat{\delta})-m(f,b,\hat{\delta})||\leq \epsilon$ ?

Comment: Yes.  If $o(f,b)=0$, then given $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$ such that $M(f,b,\delta)-m(f,b,\delta)<\epsilon$ -- and $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq M-f$ when $x,y$ are within $\delta$ of $b$. Let $y = b$.

Comment: @RRL Maybe a bit of a late question, maybe I'm writing for luck; why don't you guarantee that $M(f, b, \delta)-m(f, b, \delta)$ is greater than $-\epsilon$?

Comment: @Wrloord:  We always have $M(f,b,\delta) - m(f,b,\delta) \geqslant 0$.

Comment: $M$ is the supremum and $m$ is the infimum over the same set.

Comment: @RRL This was just what I wanted to know, I appreciate it!

Comment: @RRL Another question, and perhaps I may seem annoying but I excuse myself.  But why is it used that $f(x) < f(b) + \epsilon/2$ and $f(y) > f(b) - \epsilon/2$? I think they have nothing to do with $\sup \{f(x):x \in D , ||x-b||< \hat{\delta}\} \leq f(b) + \epsilon/2$ and $\inf \{f(x):x \in D , ||x-b||< \hat{\delta}\} \geq f(b) - \epsilon/2$ Since these latter inequalities could be argued by the property of approximation of the infimum and supremum.